# Null Pointer Exception in Method Which Sets the Parameters for Prepared Statement

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2, prepared-statement

I Have Looke over the internet that from Last 12 hours , and found that too many Users are facing that Problem , But None of them are Able to get Rid of That, 
I hav Created a JDialog , Which have TextFields, and i am Trying to get Input From those text Fields, and Store That In DataBase, 
But is Givi the Following Exception.

```
Exception occurred during event dispatching:
Connection ok
Adnan
java.lang.NullPointerException
at srvrDataBaseClass.setPersonStatement(srvrDataBaseClass.java:90)
at srvrDataBaseClass.insertPerson(srvrDataBaseClass.java:71)
at EnrollmentForm.setPerson(EnrollmentForm.java:90)
```

Here is the Code Where the StackTrac is Pointing ,

```
public void setPersonStatement(String nm,String fn,String cn,String add, byte[] fpt) {
    String Sql = "INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, FNAME, CNIC, ADDR, FPT) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        if(con==null){
            System.out.println("Connection error");   <---------------- Connection is Not Closed
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Connection ok");    <------Connection ok
        }


        con.prepareStatement(Sql);

    System.out.println(nm);     <----- This is Line :90,  But You can see its not Null, as the Value 'Adnan' is printed on cmd,
    pst2.setString(1, nm);
    pst2.setString(2, fn);
    pst2.setString(3, cn);
    pst2.setString(4, add);
    pst2.setBytes(5, fpt);

    pst2.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("SQL Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

So Any One Who can tell me , Whats Wrong with my Code

Note: DataBase is SQL Server 2008,

Comment: That line cannot (well it could, but i don't see you changing `System.out`) throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: exactly; this line is wrong: con.prepareStatement(Sql);  not assigned to anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean to do

```
pst2 = con.prepareStatement(Sql);
```

? It seems like `pst2` is `null` and will remain so in

```
pst2.setString(1, nm);
```

which probably actually throws the NPE.

Check out the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29) for the method you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks, And Now i got another Error Message.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)

Comment: @AdnanAhmadKhan That's a different problem altogether. You would probably be better off looking for related questions or asking a new one with all the details provided. Check your table schema. Does the `byte[]` make sense as something you would enter into that column?

Answer (score 1):

```
con.prepareStatement(Sql);
```

is not assigned to a proper PreparedStatement Variable,

write as

```
pst2= con.prepareStatement(Sql);
```